# R vectorize comparison to lists of start and end vectors, respectively

Tags: r

I have:

- a dataframe `DATA` containing many numeric columns with the names: `X1, X2, X3, ...` (the number of columns is variable)
- numeric vectors `start1, start2, start3, ...` (as many as the columns of `DATA`) and `End1, End2, End3, ...` (as many as the columns of `DATA`)

I want to add a column called `Result` to `DATA`, where the nth element of Result: `DATA$Result[n]` is TRUE if all the following conditions are true:

- nth value of `DATA$X1` is between `start1[n]` and `End1[n]` and
- nth value of `DATA$X2` is between `start2[n]` and `End2[n]` and....

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @DD chen - thanks for your question! We are happy to help, but to help us help you, please post what you've tried so far, along with a `dput` sample of the data you're working with.

Comment: Sorry for not giving more details, I will be more careful next time. thanks

Comment: Really if you have variable numbers of arguments, it would be better to have `start1, start2, start3, ...` as one n x m array `start`, and ditto `End1, End2, End3, ...` as one n x m array `end`. Or at least, `cbind` them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to load all the 'start', 'end' vectors into a `list` and then use `Map` to do the corresponding column, 'start', 'end' comparison

```
startLst <- mget(ls(pattern = "^start\\d+$"))
endLst <- mget(ls(pattern = "^End\\d+$"))
xcols <- grep("^X\\d+", names(DATA), value = TRUE)
resultcols <- sub("^X", "Result", xcols)
DATA[resultcols] <- Map(function(vec, st, ed) vec >= st & vec < ed, 
            DATA[xcols], startLst, endLst)
```

---

It can also done without a loop

```
DATA[resultcols] <-  DATA[xcols] >= do.call(cbind, startLst) & 
                     DATA[xcols] < do.call(cbind, endLst)
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the `length` of each 'start', 'end' vector to be the same as the number of rows of 'DATA'

---

Or this can be done in `tidyverse` as

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
pmap_dfc(list(DATA[xcols],
          startLst,
           endLst), ~ ..1 >= ..2 & ..1 < ..3)) %>%
    rename_all(~ resultcols) %>%
    bind_cols(DATA, .)
```

Comment: `dplyr` has a [`between(x, startval, endval)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/between) function. Although that's `left <= x <= right`, note that both ends are inclusive.

Comment: @smci  Yes, I initially had the `between`, but later I removed it as I was not sure about what 'startval' and 'endval' is